# Does std::is_nothrow_move_constructible require a noexcept destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, type-traits

The following code fails to compile with Visual Studio 2017 (15.5), gcc 6.4.0 and clang 4.0.1, i.e. the static assertions are failing:

```
struct Type
{
  Type(Type&&) noexcept {}

  ~Type() noexcept(false) {}
};

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Type>::value, "Type should be nothrow-move-constructible");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_constructible<Type, Type&&>::value, "Type should be nothrow-constructible from Type&&");
```

Is this correct by the C++ standard? Does `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` require a *noexcept* destructor? Why?

If I use this such as:

```
Type a;
Type b(std::move(a));
```

the destructor of `a` is not called during the second statement.

Comment: fyi only: following the chain (starting with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible ) `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` -> `std::is_nothrow_constructible`  you get to this note here: _"In many implementations, is_nothrow_constructible also checks if the destructor throws ..."_ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for the hint! Since this explicit references "many implementations", this sounds like this behaviour is not standard-conformant. I would be surprised if the standard left this as a choice to implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` is defined in terms of [is_­nothrow_­constructible_­v](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible). So this ends up being covered by [LWG issue 2116: is_nothrow_constructible and destructors](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2116)
 which is not resolved, so it is not a bug unless the issue get resolved differently then how the implementations currently act.

It opens with the following discussion:

> IMO if we specified is_[nothrow_]constructible in terms of a variable
>   declaration whose validity requires destructibility, it is clearly a
>   bug in our specification and a failure to realize the actual original
>   intent. The specification should have been in terms of placement-new.
>
> Daniel: **At the time of the specification this was intended and the
>   solution is not done by removing the destruction semantics of
>   is_constructible.**
>
> **The design of is_constructible was also impacted by the previous
>   Constructible concept that explicitly contained destruction semantics**,
>   because during conceptification of the library it turned out to
>   simplify the constraints in the library because you did not need to
>   add Destructible all the time. It often was implied but never spoken
>   out in C++03.
>
> Pure construction semantics was considered as useful as well, so
>   HasConstructor did also exist and would surely be useful as trait as
>   well.
>
> Another example that is often overlooked: This also affects wrapper
>   types like pair, tuple, array that contain potentially more than one
>   type: This is easy to understand if you think of T1 having a deleted
>   destructor and T2 having a constructor that may throw: Obviously the
>   compiler has potentially need to use the destructor of T1 in the
>   constructor of std::pair to ensure that the core language
>   requirements are satisfied (All previous fully constructed sub-objects
>   must be destructed).
>
> The core language also honors this fact in [class.copy] p11:
>
> > A defaulted copy/move constructor for a class X is defined as deleted (9.4.3 [dcl.fct.def.delete]) if X has:
> >         […]
> >      — any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member of a type with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the
> >     defaulted constructor,
> >         […]
>
> Dave: This is about is_nothrow_constructible in particular. The fact
>   that it is foiled by not having a noexcept dtor is a defect.

it concludes with:

> Ville would like "an evolution group" to take a look at this issue.

and from [this gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51452) at least gcc will be waiting for the issue to be resolved.

Also see [Non-trivial destructor make class non-trivially-constructible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33909390/1708801) which covers some other references to a related issue. Also note the [clang bug for this](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39175).